# How to reload system-connections files?

Tags: linux, systemd, networkmanager, configuration-managment

After I edit a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` I tried:

```
nmcli conn reload
systemctl daemon-reload 
systemctl reload NetworkManager
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

but no matter what, I cannot see the changes to the file (via `nmcli conn show myconnection`) unless I reboot.

I don't think the type of change was relevant, but it was adding peers to a wg config file.

File permissions are correct (`root.root 0600`). I'm editing existing ones, not creating new files.

Answer (score 0):

After rebooting this time and also not seeing the changes, I noticed my mistake was a typo in the file. All the values under the section header with a typo were ignored and no warning generated.

`nmcli conn reload` is all that is needed if there's no typos.